# Why don't work slider in asp content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a master page where all references are linked that i need (i use `Materialize-CSS`) and in one page that use this master page don't work the slider, well the slider only show a grey screen, and if a click in view image this show the image, i read that maybe `javascript` is not enable but is enable, also i try to reference all in the `ContentPlaceHolderID`="head" but is the same only show the grey screen

**Head of master page**

```
<head runat="server">
<link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/EstilosMUVIPA.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagenes/MUVIPA.ico" />    
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<%--nueva--%>
<%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">--%>

<%--termina--%>
<title>MUVIPA STORE</title>    
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Head of asp content**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>          

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').slider({ full_width: true });
    });
</script>   
</asp:Content>
```

**The slider code**

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="Imagenes/paisaje-10.jpg"/> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="Imagenes/Paisaje-Natural.jpg"/> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="Imagenes/Paisaje.jpg"/> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption right-align">
          <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="Imagenes/paisajes-bonitos-de-otoño-lago.jpg"/> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are using a slider but are you really looking for tabs or an accordion?

Comment: yes i want tabs, well i want this [link](http://materializecss.com/media.html) where said slider i try without the master page and works but when i try using a master show me a grey screen

Comment: it looks to me like the jquery slider is overwriting the media-materialize slider.  Try loading jquery first.